# Angular router - Should isActive() identify the main route, when a secondary routes is also open?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm finding that `router.isActive` is returning `false` any time a secondary route is open.

Is `router.isActive` suitable for checking *'am I on route (x)?'* (e.g.: payments page) - regardless of hashstates, query params *and secondary routes*.

Should `router.isActive` be the right service/call to deduce this? Or is it intended for something simpler. Is there an alternative? Should write my own service?

E.g.:

- When on `/second`, `router.isActive('second', true)` === true

  - (good)
- When on `second(modal:my-modal)`, `router.isActive('second', true)` === false

  - **The issue:** This function is now no longer useful to determine if I'm on the *second* page
- When on `/second`, `router.isActive('', false)` === true. (non-exact matches return true parent/child states

I've created a [plnkr proof of concept](http://embed.plnkr.co/ZDSzer/), for easier testing:

[image]

Comment: you are on "/second(popup:global-popup)" url. so what isActive('/second', true) should return true? probably isActive('/second(popup:global-popup)', true) will return true.

Comment: Thanks. What I'm looking for is a "am I on this page?" function, which will ignore secondary routes, querystring params, hashstates, or any other non-primary (route) page identifier.

Comment: Funny! I'm having the opposite problem. I get `router.isActive(...) == true` for ANY value. eg. `router.isActive('blah', 'does', 'not', exist') is true`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking a look at the source here:

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/router.ts#L493

So you specify a `urlTree` or a string, and whether an exact match is necessary.

Lets take a look at what it does after that.

`return containsTree(this.currentUrlTree, urlTree, exact);`

So lets look at `containsTree`.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/router/src/url_tree.ts#L16

Looks like it does an exact comparison vs. a contains against the tree depending on the value of `exact`.

A bit more investigation leads us here:

```
export function shallowEqual(a: {[x: string]: any}, b: {[x: string]: any}): boolean {
  const k1 = Object.keys(a);
  const k2 = Object.keys(b);
  if (k1.length != k2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  let key: string;
  for (let i = 0; i < k1.length; i++) {
    key = k1[i];
    if (a[key] !== b[key]) {
      return false;
    }
  }


 return true;
}
```

So it looks like the `urlTree` comparisons are done using a 'generic' shallow comparison algorithm to determine exactness.  That makes me think that the current `isActive()` method is not robust enough (or was intentionally designed that way) to make determinations at the level of granularity you need.

I'm not certain if there is a better way (other than maybe parsing it yourself), or if this is intentional for the `isActive()` method.  I would guess that the `isActive()` method (when using exactness) was probably written this way because the term `exact` implies that even having the secondary route does not yield an exact match.

It's probably worth a discussion with the Angular guys to see if there is a way you can get a hook to that information.

Comment: Thanks. I found this issue on GitHub, which covers some wider shortcomings with isActive: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13205 .

Comment: Good catch -- sounds like something that they've already noted and will hopefully address soon.